# How to recognize start of authentication flow in new Google Identity Services library?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-signin

While migrating to the new Google Identity Services client library, I noticed that there is no way to get notified when the authentication flow actually starts, i.e. when the user has clicked the *Sign in with Google* button. Such a callback, however, is needed to instruct other (React) components to reset their state, especially when performing multiple login attempts upon failure and mixing this with a password-based sign in or other social providers.

Previously, this was possible by overloading the button's `onClick` handler. This approach does not work anymore since the button will be injected as an `iframe`.

How can I now recognize when a user has clicked *Sign in with Google*?

See JavaScript API reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now use the [`click_listener`](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#click_listener) property to specify a function to be called when the Sign in with Google button is clicked.

The property is also available in the [HTML reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#click_listener)